# "Attempted to set property value on a null object"

Tags: wicket

I have written a wicket application to filter records based on given input. I get the error as

> Attempted to set property value on a null object. Property expression: code Value: ad

where, 
Code is the name of the field & ad is value entered to filter on.

Comment: You're trying to set a property value on a null object. Without you presenting some code, that's the most I can say.

Answer (score 2):

biziclop answer, it is Wicket Model NullPointer. Wicekt models like PropertyModel or CompoundPropertyModel uses javabean getter/setter notation, like "customer.address.street.name". So if yo have an address value in your "customer" object set to null, and wicket would attempt to set "street.name" from text field you will get this exception.

Comment: Actually I tried to filter records defaultly  based on a field. but after filtering i'm not able to filter with given inputs on fitertoolbar. I'm getting the above error.

Comment: I want one generic web page to be used for multiple pages which is to be filter based on one field(field different for different pages) & I should be able to filter based on given input in filter toolbar. Please suggest me a good way.

Comment: You should consider making panel component and include it in your pages. Than you can pass your filter in to display records. Or you can filter data in some controller and just pass a filtered data to display.